# Define current request var in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to define GET in REQUEST in Command file.

```
$this->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->set('id_activite', 1)
```

Does Not work because call an undefined method named "set".

And

```
$this->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->set('id_activite', 1);
```

Does not work because because trying to get property of non-object

I want to define request in Command file, **because I use others services after** (and services use request_stack > request)

Comment: you can manually create a new request and pass it to the service as `$request = Request::create("?".$report->getQueryString());`

Answer (score 1):

If you like to really override _GET, _POST, ... variables then you can use special request method **overrideGlobals** http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#simulating-a-request.

However it's better to push request to request_stack and it will be passed to controllers after kernel->handle() is called.

And to get request in services it's better to use request_stack also.